# Debugging UIAutomation scripts in Instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I have recently tried using UIAutomation framework for some simple automated UI tests for iOS devices. While interesting and relatively powerful, I find it quite tedious to write the scripts without having the possibility of debugging them.

Is there any way to debug the UIAutomation scripts ? The emphasis here is on the debugging of the script itself, i.e. the javascript part, I have already found the explanation of how to debug the tested application itself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472187/how-to-get-uiautomation-simulator-and-xcode-debugger-running-at-the-same-time).

Comment: Interesting question - too bad that there are no answers.

Answer (score 1):

I use these techniques to debug UI Automation scripts:

- window.logElementTree();  // to see where you are in the UI structure
- UIALogger.logMessage(msg);  // ... and where you are in your script

Jonathan Penn describes it [here](http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/05/uiautomation-an-introduction.html).